Position text in a plot with varying axis scales
I have the following plot:
Manipulate[
 ReImPlot[
  CosIntegral[n - k*u], {u, -1, n + 1}, 
   Epilog -> {{Dashed, Darker[Gray], InfiniteLine[{{n, 0}, {n, 1}}]},
    Text["n", {n + 0.1*n, 0.5}],
    {Dashed, Darker[Gray],
    InfiniteLine[{{k, 0}, {k, 1}}]}, 
    Text["k", {k - 0.1*k, 0.5}]}], 
{n, 2, 10, 1}, {k, 1, 9, 1}, ControlType -> Setter]

Measured against the plot as a whole, the positioning of the Text labels specified in Epilog of course varies depending on n and k - and as you can see from the second plot, that isn't always ideal.

Is there a way to specify the position of the Text labels so that they are always in the same position in relation to the overall framing of the plot? I'd like them near the top and just to the side of the relevant lines, regardless of the vertical and horizontal PlotRange.

I think you're going to want to specify some sort of PlotRange. Without that, your vertical lines don't even show up sometimes, so the labeling is irrelevant. You can use Scaled to position things according to the bounding box of the graph rather than the coordinate system used for the plot. So, maybe something like this:
Manipulate[
  ReImPlot[CosIntegral[n - k*u], {u, -1, n + 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{Automatic, Max[k, n] + 1}, {Automatic, 1}},
    Epilog ->
      {{Dashed, Darker[Gray], InfiniteLine[{{n, 0}, {n, 1}}]},
       Text["n", Scaled[{.03, -.05}, {n, 1}]],
       {Dashed, Darker[Gray], InfiniteLine[{{k, 0}, {k, 1}}]},
       Text["k", Scaled[{-.03, -.05}, {k, 1}]]}],
    {n, 2, 10, 1},
    {k, 1, 9, 1},
    ControlType -> Setter]


Many thanks @lericr - a definite improvement!
